# Conditional folder sharing

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a PathEdit control for folder that I intend to share as well. I want to allow user
to enter UNC path as well in the same PathEdit control (which is supported).

The problem is, when UNC path is being entered, during installation it attempts to share it.

How can I make it not to share in case if its UNC path?

Here is code snippets:

PathEdit control definition:

```
<!-- Target audio files directory -->
        <Control Id="lblAudioFilesDirectory" Type="Text" X="20" Width="100" Y="135" Height="18" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.AudioFilesDirectoryLabel)" />
        <Control Id="peAudioFilesDirectory" Type="PathEdit" X="120" Width="180" Y="135" Height="18" Property="PROP_AUDIODIR" Indirect="yes" />
        <Control Id="btnAudioFilesDirectory" Type="PushButton" X="305" Width="20" Y="135" Height="18" Text="!(loc.Browse)">
          <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[PROP_AUDIODIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="Custom_BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        </Control>
```

The Directory fragment:

```
<Directory Id="AUDIOFOLDER" Name="AudioFiles">
    <Component Id="cmpAUDIOFOLDER" Guid="{8BCFBEA2-9E7B-4E45-8838-6A71216C9B20}">
    <CreateFolder />
    <util:User Id="Everyone" Name="Everyone"></util:User>
    <util:FileShare Id="fsAudioFiles" Description="Audio files" Name="AudioFiles">
    <util:FileSharePermission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
    </util:FileShare>
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

Can I do some conditional work on

```
<util:User Id="Everyone" Name="Everyone"></util:User>
        <util:FileShare Id="fsAudioFiles" Description="Audio files" Name="AudioFiles">
        <util:FileSharePermission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
        </util:FileShare>
```

to make it work only if path is not UNC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Component` is the atomic unit of install in the Windows installer so that is what you'll want to `Condition`. Assuming the `Directory/@Id` of the folder in question is `AudioFiles` you could do something like:

```
<Component Id="cmpAUDIOFOLDER" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE"
           Directory="AudioFiles">
   <!-- If the AudioFiles directory starts with a double backslash, it's a network
        share, so share it with everyone. -->
   <Condition>AudioFiles &lt;&lt "\\"</Condition>

   <CreateFolder />
   <util:FileShare Id="fsAudioFiles" Description="Audio files" Name="AudioFiles">
     <util:FileSharePermission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
   </util:FileShare>
</Component>
```

Comment: What i was needed is <Condition><![CDATA[ NOT(AUDIOFOLDER << "\\")]]></Condition>. Thanks for the right direction